# Shapefile Features that were once KML features will not convert to MapInfo

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, kml, convert, mapinfo

I am working on a process where routes are created in [My Maps](http://google.com/maps/d). These files are then exported to a KML file that is then converted to Shapefile in ArcGIS. These features are then merged with the old set of files replacing the corresponding route.

Once this is completed the shapefile is then opened in QGIS and then I do a right-click > Save as > WGS 1984 > MapInfo MIF.

At this point an error will appear. The file is generated, but the three features that were not written are the features that once were KML features.

*update*
I have been able to convert KML files directly over to MapInfo files, but there are still some edits that need to be made in both the attribute table and geography of the files. However, I am unable to edit both KML and MapInfo files in QGIS.

Has anyone encountered this issue or are there some features that are left unchanged when files convert from KML to a Shapefile?

[image: Conversion Error]

Comment: Why not do the whole process in QGIS? QGIS allows you to convert KML  files to shapefiles (or KML files to MapInfo MIF files directly).

Comment: actually I had the same thought. unfortunately, the same issue keep occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade to  QGIS. In version 2.14 there are added capabilities surrounding MapInfo files. These upgrades include editing capabilities of Mapinfo files and the ability to convert Shapefiles that were once KML into Mapinfo files.